# Import Bitcoin core pubkey into Electrum for multisig setup

Tags: electrum, multi-signature, public-key

### Background

I have a service running on a server using bitcoin core that is signing transactions from a Bitcoin wallet automatically. However, if anyone were to get access to this server, they'd have access to the full Bitcoin keys.

Hence, I was trying to create a multi-sig setup using Electrum on bitcoin core as follows:

- I started to create a 2 of 3 multi-sig in Electrum where my plan was to have 1 key in the server (bitcoin core) and 2 keys are in Electrum instances, i.e., I'd always have to come online to verify that the transaction is made correctly.
- I managed to create two Electrum wallets and export their pubkeys to add them to the 2 of 3 multi-sig.
- I got stuck on importing a pubkey from bitcoin core into Electrum. As far as I understand, bitcoin core does not support extended pub keys ([How do I export an xpub from Bitcoin Core for use in BTCPayServer?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90135/how-do-i-export-an-xpub-from-bitcoin-core-for-use-in-btcpayserver)).

### Question

Is there any way to import a pubkey for a single address from bitcoin core into Electrum?

### Related

I found posts on how to import xpub keys into core ([Create multisignature wallet from xpub keys in bitcoin core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86059/create-multisignature-wallet-from-xpub-keys-in-bitcoin-core)) but I'm trying to do the opposite (pubkey from bitcoin core into Electrum).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Descriptor wallets, you can get the descriptors used by the wallet with the `listdescriptors` RPC. These descriptors will contain xpubs that you can import.

Without descriptor wallets, you can only get individual pubkeys from Bitcoin Core by using `getaddressinfo` for an address in the wallet.