# bitcoin core generate xpub (not hardened) from pubkey

Tags: bitcoin-core, xpub

I am a vendor in a marketplace that accepts bitcoin.

In bitcoin core that I run, I retrieved `pubkey` of my wallet by running `getaddressinfo`. Now, I need to generate an `xpub` key and pass it on to the marketplace, so that they can derive addresses for me to receive payments, one per order.

Howe do I retrieve and `xpub` key by using bitcoin core so that that key is usable by the marketplace and 1) will allow them to generate multiple child public keys (= one-time addresses for per-order payments), and 2) will allow me to view all the incoming payments, and spend them.

Comment: Maybe duplicated: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90135/how-do-i-export-an-xpub-from-bitcoin-core-for-use-in-btcpayserver

Comment: Which version of Bitcoin Core are you using? What version did you use to generate your wallet? (Is a Descriptor Wallet?)

Comment: @Murch Bitcoin Core version v22.0.0 for both.